# Odoo: how to get a specific action view by id in js action?

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I wrote my own action for "mail.message" model, and form for it.
I do this, because i want to open another form view in a specific situation.
Here is view:

```
<record id="action_view_mail_html_message" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Повідомлення</field>
    <field name="res_model">mail.message</field>
    <field name="view_mode">form</field>
    <field name="view_id" ref="mail_message_view_html_form"/>
</record>
```

in js module I call action to open message form by this way:

```
const action = {
    name: "Розширене форматування",
    type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
    res_model: 'mail.message',
    views: [[false, 'form']],
    res_id: this.message.id,
    target: 'new',
    context: {
        context: {form_view_initial_mode: 'edit'},
    },
};
this.env.bus.trigger('do-action', {
    action,
});
```

but Odoo open a default action. How to get my onw action by id?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using rpc.query to call a custom route and in that HTTP route, fetch the action by ID and return it to JS.
Once the RPC call is done, you can get your custom action.

It might be patch work but will work.